# In H2, is "TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4" working only for local/embedded databases?

Tags: java, database, h2

I tried using "TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4" on a server/tcp

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/" + f.toURI() +";TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4;", "sa", "");
```

and set the log level to warning with

```
java.util.logging.Logger h2database = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("h2database");
h2database.setLevel(Level.WARNING);
```

and all that I got was this message in scan123db.trace.db

```
01-24 15:04:14 database: org.h2.message.TraceWriterAdapter
org.h2.message.DbException: Class "org.h2.message.TraceWriterAdapter" not found [90086-169]
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:158)
at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.setLevelFile(TraceSystem.java:199)
at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:519)
at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:222)
at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:217)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:56)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:159)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:138)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:121)
at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:136)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Class "org.h2.message.TraceWriterAdapter" not found      [90086-169]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at org.h2.message.TraceWriterAdapter.<init>(TraceWriterAdapter.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at org.h2.message.TraceSystem.setLevelFile(TraceSystem.java:197)
... 9 more
```

I do wonder why?

Comment: It seems the class `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory` is missing on the server side. But the option `TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4` does currently not affect the client for the client/server case.

Comment: The H2 server was started through a h2.bat and those errors started to show after I ran the client and they were reported by the client.

Answer (score 1):

As documented, the option `TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=4` is for "[Using Other Logging APIs](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#other_logging)". If you use it, then this "Other Logging API" also needs to be in the classpath, on the server side. As written in the documentation, "To use SLF4J, all required jar files need to be in the classpath."